# Transformar sql em orm do django

Tags: sql, django, orm

Não sei como escrever este código sql na orm do django, não encontrei nada equivalente na documentação, alguém sabe como fazer?

`select coluna, split_part(split_part('string', '$', 2), '/', 1) as nova_coluna from tabela`

Answer (score -2):

Você deve usar o método `raw()` para passar queries sql puras e retornar instâncias de um model

```
Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person')
```

Pode encontrar mais exemplos [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)

Answer (score -2):

A solução que encontrei:

```
Precos.objects.filter(cod__produto=request.cod.prod).annotate(referrer_split_part=
Func(F(Func(F('recebidos'), 
Value('$'), Value(2), function='split_part')), 
Value('/'), Value(1), function='split_part')).values('recebidos_split_part')
```